# Beginner Question : How do you remove a date from a column?

Tags: r

I want to remove the date part from the first column but can't do it for all the dataset?

can someone advise please?

Example of dataset:

[image]

Comment: Hello, please, put your data here as a plain text, not a screenshot - it's better for searching for the other people. Also please add a desired output you want to get. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Just edit your question above. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sub()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) function with replacing `^[^[:alpha:]]+` ([regular expression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), i.e. all non-alphabetic characters at the beginning of the string), with `""`, i.e. empty string.

```
sub("^[^[:alpha:]]+", "", data)
```

#### Example

```r
data <- data.frame(
  good_column = 1:4,
  bad_column = c("13/1/2000pasta", "14/01/2000flour", "15/1/2000aluminium foil", "15/1/2000soap"))

data
#>   good_column              bad_column
#> 1           1          13/1/2000pasta
#> 2           2         14/01/2000flour
#> 3           3 15/1/2000aluminium foil
#> 4           4           15/1/2000soap

data$bad_column <- sub("^[^[:alpha:]]+", "", data$bad_column)

data
#>   good_column     bad_column
#> 1           1          pasta
#> 2           2          flour
#> 3           3 aluminium foil
#> 4           4           soap
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>